# How to determine the obtect's attribute and its correct function return?

Tags: python, postgresql, introspection

I am including this new function to [this S2geometry "plug"](https://github.com/AfieldTrails/s2-postgis/blob/master/s2--0.0.2.sql) that call the [this Python API](http://s2sphere.sidewalklabs.com/en/latest/api.html#s2sphere.Point)... It is simple, but I can't debug and discover the correct Python's object-attribute and array datatype, to be casted to PostgreSQL basic types.

```
CREATE FUNCTION s2_token_get_vertex(token text, k int,  OUT debug text)
AS $f$
  import s2sphere
  point = s2sphere.Cell( s2sphere.CellId.from_token(token) ).get_vertex(k)
  return ''.join(map(str,point))
$f$ LANGUAGE plpython3u IMMUTABLE;
```

- `return type(point)` is `s2sphere.sphere.Point`
- `return point.__dict__` is `{'_Point__point': (0.20907532445858387, -0.7283167971253012, 0.6525658217587561)}`
- `return map(str,point)` is `0.20907532445858387-0.72831679712530120.6525658217587561`
- `return str( point[1] )` is `<class 'float'>`

But  `return point` is an error for any of many alternatives that I tested for PostgreSQL return: `float[]`, `float4[]`, and a tuple of `(OUT x float, OUT y float, OUT z float)`...

How to determine the `point.attribute`  and its correct function return?

---

All clues say that the near to correct is to `return point` at Python code, and use `OUT r float[]` at PostgreSQL function return. But:

```
 ERROR:  invalid memory alloc request size 18446744073709551608
 CONTEXT:  while creating return value
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps PostgreSQL can't interpret array size, and considered arbitrary-length... This Python return with fixed-size array  solved the problem

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION s2_token_get_vertex(token text, k int,  OUT r float[])
AS $f$
  import s2sphere
  point = s2sphere.Cell( s2sphere.CellId.from_token(token) ).get_vertex(k)
  return (point[0],  point[1],  point[2])
$f$ LANGUAGE plpython3u IMMUTABLE;
```